# Substring in c# and add one by one

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have string 'name' and want to do substring the last number from this string.

```
string name = "1100_PF_R_06230_1";
textBox1.Text = (name.Substring(name.Length - 1, 1));
```

name string changes respectively as file number, so string name becomes.

```
1100_PF_R_06230_1
1100_PF_R_06230_2
1100_PF_R_06230_3
1100_PF_R_06230_4
1100_PF_R_06230_5
1100_PF_R_06230_6
1100_PF_R_06230_7
1100_PF_R_06230_8
1100_PF_R_06230_9
1100_PF_R_06230_10
```

when it reaches to 10 the my substring gives me 0 and file starts from 1 again. i want to substing name from last '_' underscore so that i can add number to it.

please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 string name = "1100_PF_R_06230_1";
 var num = (name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf('_')+1));
```

Comment: +1 this is likely more performant that using `Split` and `Last`.

Comment: Use `LastIndexOf('_')` instead for an increase in performance (if you're using a larger dataset/in a loop). As @juharr pointed out in my (now deleted) answer, searching for a string instead of a char slows down the call.

Comment: @keyboardP: added change as you suggested

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method with LINQ [`Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx):

```
var result =  name.Split('_').Last();
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `Split('_')` as follows

```
string strNumber = name.Split('_').Last();
```

I hope this helps.